# turning off notifications at swiftUI

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swiftui

Apple document said I can turn off notifications by calling this func: `unregisterForRemoteNotifications()`

So I made a button which can call that function like this: `Button("Hold") { unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
}`

But Xcode show me this error message 'Use of unresolved identifier 'unregisterForRemoteNotifications '

How can I fix this error? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [UIApplication instance method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623093-unregisterforremotenotifications). You should call it via `UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()`
So your code will look like:

```
Button(action: {
    UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
}) {
    Text("Perform Action")
}
```

If you use UNUserNotificationCenter you could unsubscribe from pending notifications via: `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`,
and to remove delivered use `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()`